# How to output just a page's contents in page.tpl.php in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming

I am creating a page.tpl.php template in Drupal 7 in which I want to rearrange how certain elements of the page are laid out. Specifically I want the title of the page to appear before the tabs and messages section (which I have done) and have the content of the page appear after the tabs and messages section (this is where I run into issues). I can't find a way to just render the $page['contents'] without the title. Is there a way to achieve this in Drupal 7?

I know that the node.tpl.php template handles the node specific layout, but it doesn't allow me to layout the page like as described above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethings can be done in **page.tpl.php** & some in **node.tpl.php**

Like you said, you need to make title of the node appear before tabs. You can do this in your **page.tpl.php**. Find `$title` variable as well as `$tabs` & arrange accordingly in your **page.tpl.php**. Like --

```
<?php if ($title) : ?>
  <h1 class="title">
    <?php print $title; ?>
  </h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($tabs): ?>
  <div class="tabs">
    <?php print render($tabs); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After this you will have `print render($page['content']);`, where **node.tpl.php** comes into the scene, so arranging other things like node content, comment, links you will have to go to your **node.tpl.php** & arrange accordingly. More modification such as in comment & other TPLs will come into the scene like **comment.tpl.php** etc..

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in the end where I do not print out the node's title in the node.tpl.php file to achieve the effect I am looking for. As a caveat to others who want to achieve the same thing, you will need to use a node type specific templates so as to not hide article titles when multiple articles are listed on a page.

Comment: You didn't specify the content type specific requirement, so I didn't mention anything of that regards in my answer. Anyway, node title is part of page.tpl.php not node.tpl.php..